# How to publish jar to local repository?

Tags: sbt

I have a library compiled to a jar (not an sbt project, no source code, just the jar file) that's not available on a repository.

Is there a way to publish the jar locally so I can add the dependency using the     `libraryDependencies += "org.xxx" % "xxx" % "1.0"` notation? (I already know how to add the file to a project by copying it to the `lib` folder.)

Comment: That's a very interesting question since I've seen almost no tasks that would not expect a project (except `about`). One could think of a plugin that you'd register globally and use it to publish jars to a local Ivy repository. I know no plugin that would do that.

Answer (score 66):

The **publishLocal** action is used to publish your project to a local Ivy repository. By default, this local repository is in ${user.home}/.ivy2/local. You can then use this project from other projects on the same machine [source](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Publishing.html)

EDIT: Sorry I misread your question. Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10381925/125617) to publish a jar or sources to your local ivy repo.

Comment: Right, but this isn't a project, it's a jar file.  How do I do this?

Comment: In more recent versions of sbt, this is `publishLocal`  and not `publish-local`: https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Publishing.html

Answer (score 37):

**tl;dr** I'd call it a trick not a feature of sbt. You've been warned.

Let's say you've got `file.jar` to publish. As is for *any* build tool, sbt including, it's to execute tasks that eventually create an artifact - a jar file in most cases - out of the files in a project.

The project sets *the coordinates* for the artifact.

The trick is to leverage what sbt requires to set up *the environment* (= *the coordinates*) for the jar to be published (otherwise you'd have to specify them on command line that may or may not be very user friendly).

Create a `build.sbt` with the necessary settings - `organization`, `name`, `version` and possibly `scalaVersion` - and save it where the jar file is.

```
organization := "org.abc"

name := "my-own-publish-jar"

version := "1.0.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.3"

packageBin in Compile := file(s"${name.value}_${scalaBinaryVersion.value}.jar")
```

You may've noticed, the build changes `compile:package` task to point at the jar file.

That's it.

Execute `sbt publishLocal` and the jar file should be in the Ivy2 local repository, i.e. `~/.ivy2/local/org.abc/my-own-publish-jar_2.11/1.0.0/jars/my-own-publish-jar_2.11.jar`.

**protip** Writing a plugin to do it with the coordinates specified on command line should be quite easy now.

Comment: This worked for me.  I did have to drop the `_${scalaBinaryVersion.value}` to achieve my particular goal, but otherwise this was the solution.

Comment: Yes, for a Java JAR where you don't want the Scala version, you can set `crossPaths := false` to remove it - but this should only be used for local builds when Scala binary compatibility is not a problem.

Comment: this way worked for me, but anybody can advise on how to extend it for multiple jars? thanks

Answer (score 6):

Let's say you have `wetElephant.jar` and `wetElephant-javadoc.jar` files some 3rd party library and corresponding javadocs which you want to publish to your local repo and referrence it from another project using `libraryDependencies` sbt *taskKey*.

Here's what you need to do.

1. Put your libraries (`wetElephant.jar` and `wetElephant-javadoc.jar`) into `modules\wetElephant`
2. Define project in your *build.sbt* file (or *Build.scala* file)

   ```
   lazy val stolenLib = project
     .in(file("modules/wetElephant"))
     .settings(
       organization              := "com.stolenLibs",
       name                      := "wetElephant",
       version                   := "0.1-IDonKnow",
       crossPaths                := false,  //don't add scala version to this artifacts in repo
       publishMavenStyle         := true,
       autoScalaLibrary          := false,  //don't attach scala libs as dependencies
       description               := "project for publishing dependency to maven repo, use 'sbt publishLocal' to install it",
       packageBin in Compile     := baseDirectory.value / s"${name.value}.jar",
       packageDoc in Compile     := baseDirectory.value / s"${name.value}-javadoc.jar"
     )
   ```
3. Call `publishLocal` task from sbt/activator (I did it from activator and prefixed it with proejct name):

   ```
   ./activator wetElephant/publishLocal
   ```

... and read the output to see what and where was published:

```
    /cygdrive/d/devstation-workspace/projects/m4l-patches 1
      [info] Loading project definition from D:\devstation-workspace\projects\m4l-patches\project
      [info] Set current project to m4l-patches (in build file:/D:/devstation-workspace/projects/m4l-patches/)
      [info] Updating {file:/D:/devstation-workspace/projects/m4l-patches/}wetElephant...
    [info] Packaging D:\devstation-workspace\projects\m4l-patches\modules\wetElephant\target\wetelephant-0.1-IDonKnow-sources.jar ...
    [info] Done packaging.
    [info] Wrote D:\devstation-workspace\projects\m4l-patches\modules\wetElephant\target\wetelephant-0.1-IDonKnow.pom
      [info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...4 ....
    [info] Done updating.
    [info] :: delivering :: com.stolenLibs#wetelephant;0.1-IDonKnow :: 0.1-IDonKnow :: release :: Sun Dec 20 20:09:24 CET 2015
      [info]  delivering ivy file to D:\devstation-workspace\projects\m4l-patches\modules\wetElephant\target\ivy-0.1-IDonKnow.xml
      [info]  published wetelephant to C:\Users\pawell\.ivy2\local\com.stolenLibs\wetelephant\0.1-IDonKnow\poms\wetelephant.pom
      [info]  published wetelephant to C:\Users\pawell\.ivy2\local\com.stolenLibs\wetelephant\0.1-IDonKnow\jars\wetelephant.jar
      [info]  published wetelephant to C:\Users\pawell\.ivy2\local\com.stolenLibs\wetelephant\0.1-IDonKnow\srcs\wetelephant-sources.jar
      [info]  published wetelephant to C:\Users\pawell\.ivy2\local\com.stolenLibs\wetelephant\0.1-IDonKnow\docs\wetelephant-javadoc.jar
      [info]  published ivy to C:\Users\pawell\.ivy2\local\com.stolenLibs\wetelephant\0.1-IDonKnow\ivys\ivy.xml
      [success] Total time: 1 s, completed 2015-12-20 20:09:24
```

4. Optionally use these libraries in another project

   ```
   libraryDependencies += "com.stolenLibs" % "wetElephant" % "0.1-IDontKnow"
   ```

Disclaimer: I don't know how not to publish sources...

Comment: This does not work. the scala version is always 2.10 and the version is always 0.1.snapshot.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a blog post I followed to push sbt artifact to a maven repository (local and remote) a few months ago.

http://brizzled.clapper.org/id/100/

Comment: Thanks, but I already know how to publish an sbt project to my local repository.  What I was asking about was how to add a single existing jar file to my local repository.  Do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Comment: -1, maven has nothing to do with this question, although not your fault OP added the "maven" tag to this.

Comment: haha although not your fault so -1.  He has a jar file he needs in a repository, maven is a repository.

Comment: @cbmanica  Roy is correct here. I am upvoting to cancel your misguided downvote.

Answer (score -1):

I created a sample Play Framework/sbt project that creates a local repository (not just `publish-local`) here: https://github.com/muymoo/local-ivy-repo-sbt
Specifically look at `Build.scala`

`makeLocalRepoSettings(publishedProjects):_*`

and

`localRepoArtifacts += "org.apache.ws.security" % "wss4j" % "1.6.9"`

These `localRepoArtifacts` are found in my local ivy repo, but I think you could edit this to work with plain old jar files as well.

To run: `play local-repository-created`

It is a simpler version of https://github.com/sbt/sbt-remote-control which does a whole lot more in their `Build.scala`.