# Publish single 3rd party jar to local repository in sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a project which depends on a 3rd party jar `SomeJar.jar`.

How can I make a specific sub project cause this jar to be published to local repository before the sub project runs its own compile?

In the example below, `somejar-common` needs to first be published to local repo.

```
lazy val subproj1 = (project in file("subproj1"))
    .settings(libraryDependencies += "org.someorg" % "somejar-common" % "1.0.0") // This one needs to be deployed first to local repo
```

Comment: publishing manually once isn't enoug? If it's a third party how often are you predicting it'll change?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to publish jar to local repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798767/how-to-publish-jar-to-local-repository)

Answer (score 2):

If your (sub)project depends on a fixed jar, you don't need to publish it locally to work with it. You can add it as an unmanaged dependency: just put it in your (sub)project's `lib/` subfolder.

See sbt [documentation on unmanaged dependencies](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Library-Dependencies.html#Unmanaged+dependencies).